# Docker Postgres running multiple dockers with segregated instances

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a requirement with docker/docker-compose to run 2 different instances of postgres but i need their data to be completely separate as both applications control the database server completely, not just a single database

Here is the docker file there is one in each project directory

```
FROM postgres:10-alpine
COPY data/resources.sql.gz /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/resources.sql.gz
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
```

Here is the section from each docker compose, there is one in each project directory

Project 1

```
db_test:
   image: postgres:10-alpine
   container_name: postgres_test
   restart: always
   expose:
    - '5432'
   environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
    - PGDATA=/db
   volumes:
    - ./db:/db
   networks:
     backend:
       ipv4_address: 172.16.1.6
```

Project 2

```
 db:
   image: postgres:10-alpine
   container_name: postgres
   restart: always
   expose:
    - '5432'
   environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
    - PGDATA=/db
   volumes:
    - ./db:/db
   networks:
     backend:
       ipv4_address: 172.16.0.6
```

I should also note that the resources.sql.gz is unique to each project

The problem i am having is that i build project 1, then stop the docker

then i build project 2 and for some reason its inheriting the databases from project 1

what i need is to completely seperate both so that i could run them side by side with different ports (if required)

Comment: Are both of those YAML files in the same directory?  It looks like you're using the same `./db` host directory for both databases, so they'll be the same.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create two distinct docker volumes:

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.7"

volumes:
  db1-pgdata-volume:
    name: db1-postgres-data
  db2-pgdata-volume:
    name: db2-postgres-data

services:
  db_test:
     image: postgres:10-alpine
     container_name: postgres_test
     restart: always
     expose:
      - '5432'
     environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - PGDATA=/db
     volumes:
      - db1-pgdata-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     networks:
       backend:
         ipv4_address: 172.16.1.6
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
    - PGDATA=/db
    volumes:
      - db2-pgdata-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same database storage for both services. It's like you're using a single database with two access points.

Change the `volumes` section to this :

- in `db` service :

```
volumes:
  - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

- in `db_test` service:

```
volumes:
  - ./db_test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Remove the following from the `environment` section :

```
- PGDATA=/db
```